# R Cannot be Resolved to a Variable after Cleaning and Building Project

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, r.java-file

Although I know this question has been asked a million times, I have tried going through many of the stackoverflow questions and none of the answers have worked.

I have an old version of my project that I know worked and built correctly, which I added back into my eclipse workspace. When I clean and build the project, I am given with errors with the R cannot be resolved..

What I've tried:
- Building/Cleaning project
- Was going to clear the gen folder, BUT R.java didn't even exist in there
- Checking through my XML files to ensure there's no errors
- Restarting Eclipse

Extra note:
- My ADT plugin and Android SDK was the LAST version directly after Google released it's updates to merge everything over to Android Studio.

Comment: the number of "R cannot be resolved" question is too damn high .... Please search and you will find thousands of thread

Comment: Yes, but my solution/problem wasn't caused by the same things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying everything I tried one last thing.. which was to update all of my plugins and libraries for Android. This actually solved the issue. I'm sure not that many people will probably have my specific issue since it will eventually go away, but it is a different problem I have not found and a different solution I have also not found...

Comment: I had the same issue. I did a `Project->Clean (& Build)`. After that, all my Activity classes showed this error (R Cannot be Resolved). My errors went away by doing a `Project->Build Project`. I didn't have to   update any plugins/libraries

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this problem for myself. I was using the Eclipse Android SDK on Windows 7. The problem was that the Eclipse program did not have permission to create the R file. To fix it I went to "User Account Control" settings in the Windows Control panel and lowered the slider to a lower security level. After rebooting the computer and cleaning the application in Eclipse Android SDK there were no more errors.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced the same problem a week ago. After installing the beta version of android studio I was unable to run android projects in eclipse. Uninstalling android studio fixed all the "R cannot be resolved to.." errors.

Answer (score 1):

I faced Simmilar problem, i cleaned project, Restarted Eclipse, and many other things like remove errors from problems, 
but it was DUE TO: an Image Name in Drawable it contained Capital Latter i did Re factor -->Rename and Problem solved..